# In erlang/OTP how do I start appmon to monitor an existing node?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a running erlang application, launched with this command line

```
erl -boot start_sasl -config config/cfg_qa -detached -name peasy -cookie peasy -pa ./ebin -pa ./ebin/mochiweb -s peasy start
```

If I start a new node and run appmon:start(), the 'peasy' node won't show up, even if using the same cookie. The same happens with webtool:start()

Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found.

As always with erlang, to have two nodes speak to each other, you need to ping:

```
1> net_adm:ping(other_node_you_want_to_monitor).
pong
2> appmon:start().
{ok,<0.48.0>}
```

And off you go :)

Comment: Actually, any way to look up the atom to see if there is a node by that name. Ping happen to be an easy schmeasy way to make that happen though.